# Is their any GEF 3D application [eclipse completed plugin]?

Tags: 3d, eclipse-gef

i need GEF 3d developing software

Comment: what about http://www.eclipse.org/gef3d/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse GEF3D project (if that is what you mean by GEF 3D) comes with some sample applications, that is 3D versions of the UML2 tools (class, use case, and activity editor) and a 3D version of the Ecore tools (for Ecore diagrams). Besides, the Eclipse Agent Modeling Platform includes a GEF3D based visualization.